# Loading a jar library that loads libraries

Tags: java, class, jar, loading

Well, maybe it's convoluted, anyway...

I'm not very experienced with java, though I've dabbled in creating some Minecraft mods and Android apps.
My question is: I have a .jar that contains code that I don't have a lot of control on (I don't have the source code though I do have some infos about the classes in it), and when this jar is run it itself load some code from other external libraries and classes, and consolidate everything.

My question is then, how do I, without touching/modifying the jar, make a java program that runs the jar, let it do its consolidating from other jars and external classes, then get the results (a few objects) of that consolidating into my own java program ? Is that even permitted in the java security model ?

I've heard of URLclassloader that I think is to load load classes from a jar. It can't seem to make it work, and I'm not even sure that would work ? I know roughly which classes are entry point in the jar in order to run it and make it load the external libraries. But I always run into exceptions left and right.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your terms: "run a jar", "consolidate everything". It may also give some context if you actually name the library in question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you just trying to call classes from that jar?

Comment: To "run a jar" you must have all runtime dependencies of that jar in your classpath. And the dependencies of the dependencies as well. And so on.

Comment: OK, there probably needs some clarification. The library jar is a full blown java software, and the consolidation is in fact, at runtime, the program loads definition, etc, from external libraries, e.g. jars. To be even more clear: the program is Minecraft, more specifically a modded Minecraft installation, which can load mods from external files (zips, jars). I'd like to get some values out of the app, notably the mapping of IDs of blocks and items once all the mods are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure all 3rd partyd dependencies (e.g. libraries that your `jar` needs) are ~visible~ to your application (e.g. reside on classpath and/or `-Djava.library.path`). Next, you should just instantiate classes/call methods from your `jar` file normally and operate with returned objects as its been locally created by your Java application. `jar` file is just an external library that becomes the part of your application upon loading.

Comment: @rienafairefr A good way to control that tree of dependencies is to use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Give it a try ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I was referencing the original poster =P

Comment: When talking about `~visible~` you should probably mention the classpath.

Comment: He's speaking about `external libraries and classes` I think he mean binary libraries and jars. Ok, I'll fix my post now. Thanks.

Comment: About Maven and such, I don't think that'd would work, I want to be able to load dynamically the library at runtime (i.e. I wouldn't ship the "library jar", but users of the app would have it and tell my program where it is)

Comment: Then you should create `.bat` or `.sh` file to run your java application. That file will ask user for location of additinal libraries and modify classpath `-classpath` or just `-cp` command line option when start your application.